# How to detect synchronous calls made by my code (and not by my dependencies)?

Tags: node.js, express

In [Express best practices guide](https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html#dont-use-synchronous-functions), it says you shouldn't use synchronous functions. So they advise passing a flag `--trace-sync-io` to raise a warning anytime a synchronous operation is made.

So I did, but when I ran my app... I got thousands of warnings! Most of them were raised by my dependencies' code and that doesn't help much. I was expecting it to show problems with *my* code, for example, calls to `console.log()`, which is (most of the times) synchronous.

Is there a more readable version of this flag, or a more effective way of detecting unwanted synchronous calls?

Comment: Are you getting thousands of warnings AFTER your server starts up?  It's normal to use synchronous code in startup (even `require()` uses synchronous I/O).  So, ignore the startup warnings and only pay attention to things that are happening AFTER your server has started up and is now processing incoming requests.  You can log something in the first request your server receives and start looking from there.

Comment: Node.js itself doesn't know the different between your code and your dependencies so it's not going to separate those out.